# How to remove info from inside tags from a variable

Tags: php, regex

I have this text in a variable, lets say **$textvariable**:

```
<p>Hello everybody I would like</p>
<p><output tipo="youtube" valor="5ZzklOEGW0w"><em>youtube: 5ZzklOEGW0w</em></output></p>
<p>to party a lot</p>
<p><output tipo="youtube" valor="RW2QkfIytRA"><em>youtube: RW2QkfIytRA</em></output></p>
<p>Tonight</p>
```

And I would like to remove what's insede  and leave it like this:

```
<p>Hello everybody I would like</p>
<p><output tipo="youtube" valor="5ZzklOEGW0w"></output></p>
<p>to party a lot</p>
<p><output tipo="youtube" valor="RW2QkfIytRA"></output></p>
<p>Tonight</p>
```

I know the regex to find the info inside:

```
#<output>(.*?)</output>#
```

But how can I remove all information inside this tags? That can be more than one or two of this in a variable

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
preg_replace('/(<output[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/output>)/i', '$1$3', $html);
```